# Action upon Track-bar change

Tags: c#, winforms, trackbar

I want to write a C# program where if the track-bar value is 2 then it would let me "do something", I am using VS 2015.

Comment: Well it sounds like you probably need to subscribe to an event which is raised when the trackbar value changes. We don't really know what you've tried or where the problem is though...

Comment: Are you referring to the [`TrackBar` from Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar(v=vs.110).aspx)? Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: i want that if i slide the trackbar to the value 2 that it will do something i know to code to make a popup but i dont know the code that if the value of the trackbar is 2 that i can make something happen (like messageBox.Show)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the form load add event handler for Trackbar ValueChanged event.

```
TrackBar1.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(TrackBar1_ValueChanged);
```

Define the Event Handler method:

```
private void TrackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(TrackBar1.Value == 2)
    {
         // Do your actions here.
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx but i only want to do an action if its a specific value

Comment: @Chashtaglife: Welcome. The answer has been updated according to your specific requirement.

Comment: really thanks it helpt my out a lot